# Showing inequality in $L^p$ and $L^2$

Tags: inequality

I'd like to show that
\begin{align}
||f||_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \lambda_p ||f'||_{L^2(0,1)}
\end{align}
for all $f \in H^{1}_{0}(0,1)$.

I thought about doing something like
\begin{align}
\Big(\int_0^1|f(t)|^pdt \Big)^{1/p} = \Big( \int_0^1 |\int_0^t f'(s)ds|^p dt \Big)^{1/p} \leq \Big( \int_0^1 \big( \int_0^t |f'(s)|ds \big)^pdt \Big)^{1/p} 
\end{align}
but I'm not so sure if that's the way to go as I'm not sure how to proceed now. Do I need to use the Poincare inequaltiy or Sobolev embedding?

Comment: First prove $\|u\|_{L^\infty} \le C\|u'\|_{L^2}$, then show $\|u\|_{L^p}\le C\|u\|_{L^\infty}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing @Arctic Char's comment in detail.

For $f \in H^1_0(0,1)$ we write
$$|f(x)| = | \int_0^x f'(t) dt| \leq  \int_0^1 |f'(t)| dt \leq   \left(\int_0^1 |f'(t)|^2 dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \left(\int_0^1 1^2 dt \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}  = ||f'||_{L^2}. $$ Thus you get $$||f||_{\infty} \leq ||f'||_{L^2}.$$
On the other hand, we have
$$||f||^p_{L^p} = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^p dx \leq \int_0^1 ||f||_{\infty}^p dx $$
Which gives you $$||f||_{L^p} \leq ||f||_{\infty}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I did the same thing but I was confused since I don't seem to use the boundary conditions   $f(0)=f(1)=0$ amywhere. So is this true for general $f \in H^1$?

Comment: The boundary condition is used in the very first equality because we have $|\int^x_0 f'(t) dt| = |f(x) - f(0)| = |f(x)|$.

Comment: Oh yes of course! thanks

Comment: I've just came across the statement that this equality is also true for $f \in H^1$ with the additional condition that $\int_0^1f(x)dx=0$. Do you know if this can be proven similarly? (I tried it but I failed)

Comment: It is indeed true under the assumptions you mentioned. That is because this inequality does not work for constant functions other than $0$. In $H^1_0$ the only constant function is the $0$ function (because of the boundary condition). And under the assumption you gave, the only constant function in $H^1$ is still the $0$ function because the only constant function with average $0$ is the $0$. As per the proof, check this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473588/a-version-of-poincar%C3%A9s-inequality-in-one-dimension).